# Webstorm localhost from mobile

Tags: mobile, localhost, port, webstorm

I can't access my Webstrom localhost on port 63342 from mobile.
I opened the port in Windows firewall and ESET (but port online checkers say me that the port still close).
 
I checked option "Can accept external connections" in Webstorm (but it caused message that Built-in HTTP server on that port disabled).
But when I check 192.168.0.48:63342 in mobile chrome - it still not available.
Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd suggest using a different port (8080, 8090) if you need to access the server from another host. External connections to 63342 are not supported for security reasons.
Here are instruction for connecting to WebStorm internal web server from a different host:
- on a remote host, make sure to install JetBrains IDE Support extension into Chrome
- in extension options (chrome-extension://hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji/options.html), specify the IP and port of the target machine
- on a target computer, start WebStorm, make sure that the port specified in Settings/JavaScript/Debugger is the same as above and 'Can accept external connections' is on. Open your project and run your application

Comment: what authority is being used for authentication?  I am on a mac with chrome and I get the user/password dialog, but no combination is working.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the port number to something else than 63342, does work. However I had some difficulties changing the debug port number. If you have the Chrome plugin, changing the debug port number from Webstorm's settings will not override the plugin's default debug port. Thus, you should right click on the plugin, click "Options", change port number and hit apply. At the same time, you should enable external connections in Webstorm's settings: "Settings/JavaScript/Debugger". Then you can access your web app from your smartphone by specifying the IP and port address of the app.